# Do I always need to start at the begining when switching phones?

Tags: pokemon-go

My phone is broken so I have switched between 2 other phones, and when im logging in I always have to start at the beginning, so I never get to a high level! Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the information for what Pokémon you have caught, what purchases you have made (if any), how many candies you have, etc. are stored on the server.

As long as you log in to the new phone with the same account (Google if you used Google preciously Pokémon Trainer Club if that was used).